# Detect "value" by imported JS

Tags: javascript, html, token

I'm working on website where users can add projects. They can add a link of their website to project. But to verify that website is their they must add some script and generated token to head of their website index.

**I want to make something like this:**

```
<script src="linktoscript" data-sitekey="token"></script>
```

But I don't know how to load that "token" at the script.

**I tried:**

```
var token = response('data-sitekey');
```

*Didn't work.*

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please share you full code.

Comment: I didn't make the code yet. I just tried to alert() token.
```
var token = response('data-sitekey');
alert(token);
``` but nothing @Wendelin

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably [`document.currentScript`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) is what you are looking for. `document.currentScript` returns the DOM of `<script>`.

Try something like this:

```
console.log(document.currentScript.dataset.sitekey)
```

I hosted a [demo](http://so55993402.surge.sh). Use "View Source" to see the code.

Comment: This would work but you can't verfy that the script was executed on the user's website. The user could just as well run the script in their browser,

Comment: @Wendelin I don't really understand the question (so nor do I follow what you are trying to say). I'm just providing a solution which might be what OP is looking for. Also that's the reason I used the word "probably".

Comment: If you don't understand the question then don't answer it. Your answer does work but does not achieve what @WebCoder is trying to do.

Comment: @Wendelin I said "I don't **really** understand..." meaning I don't get the end goal (you  missed the really part). What I understand is OP wants the `data-sitekey` attribute via the script linked in the tag. So I thought about giving it a shot maybe it would be helpful. You did not find the answer apt, you downvoted it so good for you.

Comment: Thank you so much. Checked as best answer

Comment: @Wendelin wanna say something now? Kidding, no hard feelings xD

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution, but there are many more.
I advise you not to have them add a script to thier site. They will probably not thrust your script and refuse to let it run on their website.

Also if your script on their site sends the token to your server you cannot verify that the request actually came from their website. They could have just as well run your script on their local machiene.

### Step 1

Generate a token and store it in your DB together with the url of their website

Example token `tJ0qEKJQlp2ZXb19`

### Step 2

Ask the user to add this meta tag to their site.

Assuming your website is called `example.com`

```
<meta name="example.com-token" content="tJ0qEKJQlp2ZXb19">
```

### Step 3

Verify that the meta tag exists on their site.

In JS:

```
fetch(urlOfTheirSite, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "text/html",
  },
}).then((resp) => {
  if(!resp.ok) {
    //Cannot fetch thier website
  }
  resp.text()
}).then((html) => {
  var doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(stringContainingHTMLSource, "text/html");
  var token = doc.querySelector("meta[name=example.com-token]");
  /*
   * Send token and url of the website to your server for verification.
   * On your server check if the url and the token match the entry in your DB
   */
})
```

In PHP:

Use [cURL](https://php.net/manual/de/book.curl.php) and this RegEx

`meta\s+name="?example\.com-token"?\s*content="?(\w+)"?\s*`

The first capture group will contain the token

### Step 4

Tell your user that their site has been verified and that they can remove the meta tag now.